# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response error using SeleniumGrid

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I am implementing selenium grid and the capability to launch the tests using the RemoteWebDriver. I am using docker standalone image.
Below is my code

```
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444"),options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    driver.get("www.google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Command:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                      NAMES
1f810511cbe2   selenium/standalone-chrome:latest   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   9 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:4444-\>4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7900-\>7900/tcp, 5900/tcp   modest_keller
```

I have also added selenium-java, selenium-manager and testing dependencies in pom.xml. I am using:

- Java 11
- Selenium 4.8.0
- Selenium Manager 4.8.0
- Chrome version 109.0.5414.119
- IDE IntelliJ
- MacOS

I am getting below errors:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response:     var json = Object.freeze('{"consoleLink": "\\u002fgrid\\u002fconsole","type": "Grid Hub","class": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpHandler$DisplayHelpServletConfig","version": "3.141.59"}');
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at baseTest.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:180)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to parse: \<!DOCTYPE html\>

    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:131)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.1', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$buildCoercer$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: please, format your question properly

Answer (score 0):

Add *`/wd/hub`* at the end of the your driver URL as:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

or

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

Comment: WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), options);        By changing the local host address in the URL,  its working now. Thank you.